# ¿Qué significa la frase "me mamas morra"?

Tags: traducción, uso-de-palabras, méxico, español-neutral, hispanoamérica

Me gustaría saber qué significa la frase:

> me mama´s morra/ me mamas morra

¿Es algo feo o es una expresión en sentido positivo? Creo que este tipo de frases  se usa solo en America Latina-México. ¿Alguien que me lo podría explicar con un ejemplo en español de España o en inglés?

Answer (score 4):

A pesar de que el término "morro(a)" sí tiene origen en el norte del país, actualmente se usa de manera muy común en todo el centro y en general en las ciudades grandes.

Por su parte "Mamar" sí tiene significado de sexo oral, sin embargo tiene muchos otros, cuando se usa seguido de un sustantivo "Me mama la pizza" "Le mama Pink Floyd (a él o ella)" significa que algo le gusta mucho al sujeto. Así, la expresión "me mamas, morra" sería una forma muy informal y algo vulgar de decirle a una mujer que te gusta.

NOTA. Si tuviera el sentido de felación sería "Me **la** mamas, morra".

Answer (score 3):

A mi parecer, esta es una expresión usada sobre todo en Monterrey (México), donde el verbo `mamar` tiene significados coloquiales muy distintos al significado oficial que da la RAE.

Por partes, `morra` es una forma de llamar a cualquier mujer de forma coloquial y se utiliza en un ambiente exclusivamente informal, por ejemplo entre amigos para referirse a terceros(morro, morra), sin llegar a ser despectivo, al igual que en otros lugares del país se utiliza `chavo`/`chava`(chico/chica).

Los usos mas populares que conozco de Monterrey para este tipo de frases son:

> Se mamó: que hizo alguna cosa muy bien,  o que la hizo muy mal.

Esto es sinónimo de otra frase popular, `te la bañaste`.

Las frases y sus usos antes mencionados son muy comunes en el norte de México y originarios de Monterrey. En cualquier otro lugar del país quizá no lo entenderían en una conversación.

Particularmente la frase que mencionas en tu ejemplo no tiene mucho sentido sin el contexto adecuado. De acuerdo a mi experiencia con estas frases, te están dando a entender que no le agradas a quien te lo está diciendo. Un equivalente del coloquio Español sería:

> Me rayas tía

.

Comment: No solo Monterrey, sino también en todo el país. Son expresiones que cualquier mexicano sabe, estoy seguro que si viajas al sur del país también te podrás encontrar con las mismas frases y expresiones.

Comment: Veo mucho el uso en redes como reddit y twitter - alguien dice algo chistoso sobre algún tema o otro, otro le comenta "te mamaste "

Answer (score 0):

Es algo despectivo, o sea, algo feo como tu dices.

*Morra* es una interjección para llamar a la gata, [según la RAE](http://buscon.rae.es/drae/srv/search?id=tRVqwTfjgDXX2CFhcIKV%7CkjP92uimFDXX2bTfcXz0%7C7A4ic71RpDXX2Uoz08l9) (Real Academia Española)

En otras palabras, te esta diciendo que le *chupes el pene*, podría decírtelo en otras palabras pero no me parecen apropiadas, supongo que puedes hacerte una idea ;)).

Comment: +1, pero "practicar una felación" describe la misma acción que "chupar el pene", por si buscas un equivalente que no sea grosero.

Comment: @Diego para aclarar, _chupar el pene_ no es grosero. A menos que chupar una paleta lo sea.

Comment: @SergioVelásquez, No es eso estoy de acuerdo. De hecho, casi va al extremo completamente opuesto y suena _cursi_. Por eso, ante el "podría decírtelo en otras palabras pero no me parecen apropiadas" quise resaltar "felación". Describe la acción, no es grosero y es **otra** expresión equivalente a "chupar el pene".

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo es cursi, lo he dicho asi por no decir : "comerle la polla"

Comment: ¿A qué se refiere "intejección para llamar a la gata"? ¿La hembra del gato?: _"¡Venga, morra...! ¿Dónde está mi gatita...?"_

Answer (score 0):

"Morro" o "Morra" es "niño" o "joven", aplíquese a alguien que no ha alcanzado la madurez oficial de 18 años.
"mamas" de "mamar" es una forma vulgar de referirse a "hacer una felación"

Answer (score 0):

Es tan pero tan amplio el sentido que puede darse a esa frase, que todo va en el contexto de la conversación que estén teniendo en ese momento.  Puede ser algo tan simple como decir "me gustas" ya que en algunas ciudades mexicanas decir me mama, es sinónimo de decir me gusta. O me mamas en el sentido literal de la palabra.